# Transform array of objects to a different array of objects - Javascript/Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

I have an array of object that looks like this. I made it look that way using .groupBy with lodash.

States.ts

```
STATES: Object[] = [
  {
    USA: [
      {
        name: 'Alabama',
        abbreviation: 'AL',
        country: 'USA'
      },
      {
        name: 'Alaska',
        abbreviation: 'AK',
        country: 'USA'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Canada: [
      {
        name: 'Alberta',
        abbreviation: 'ALB',
        country: 'Canada'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I need it to look like this:

```
    stateList:StateDropdownItem[] =[ 
    {
       label: 'USA', 
       items: [
               {label: 'AL', value: 'Alabama'},
               {label: 'AK', value: 'Alaska'},
       ]
    },
    .
    .
   ]
```

I have tried the code below, but it doesn't work. When I print it to the console appears `undefiened` even if I try to put an element without the forloop I get the following error `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`

**TS**

```
dropdownOfStates: StateDropdownItem[];
.
.
dropdownBuilder() {
    const STATES_BY_COUNTRY = this.getStatesByCountry();
    let tempItem;
    for (let i = 0; i < STATES_BY_COUNTRY.length; i++) {
      tempItem = STATES_BY_COUNTRY[i];
      this.dropdownOfStates.push(
        new StateDropdownItem('KEY COUNTRY VALUE HERE', [
          tempItem.abbreviation,
          tempItem.name
        ])
      );
    }
  }
```

Console.log after printing the result of using .groupBy with lodash
[groupby objects by country](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2hsv.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. As it stands, the STATES array is not valid. Is it supposed to be an array of objects? Or a single object with values `USA`, `Canada` etc

Comment: It's an array of a module of type State that i created in a file called state.module.ts 

`export class State {
  abbreviation: string;
  name: string;
  country: string;

  constructor(abbreviation: string, name: string, country: string) {
    this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
    this.name = name;
    this.country = country;
  }
}`

Comment: Okay, can you please edit your question so that the code would compile? Thanks

Comment: @user184994 done

Comment: No, that still wouldn't compile. You can try calling `JSON.stringify` on the object coming back from lodash, that would help.

Comment: @user184994 Finally, my bad. I was trying to recreate the object that was printed to the console. I have updated my question

Comment: @user184994 I have posted a link to the picture so you can see the original structure that gets printed after using .groupBy with lodash. Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `map` function of arrays to transform their structure.

The code below should transform it into the structure you want. You can click "Run code snippet" to see the output

```js
let states = [
  {
    USA: [
      {
        name: 'Alabama',
        abbreviation: 'AL',
        country: 'USA'
      },
      {
        name: 'Alaska',
        abbreviation: 'AK',
        country: 'USA'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    Canada: [
      {
        name: 'Alberta',
        abbreviation: 'ALB',
        country: 'Canada'
      }
    ]
  }
];

// Use the code below to transform 

let res = states.map((val) => {
  let country = Object.keys(val)[0]; // Get the name of the country, e.g. USA
  return { // Return the new object structure
    label: country,
    items: val[country].map((item) => ({label: item.abbreviation, value: item.name}))
  }
});

// Log the value
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thanks so much! you are a genius. I was thinking to use .map but I wasn't sure on how to do it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Here is somewhat more concise method of doing this with ES6 and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
var data = [ { USA: [ { name: 'Alabama', abbreviation: 'AL', country: 'USA' }, { name: 'Alaska', abbreviation: 'AK', country: 'USA' } ] }, { Canada: [ { name: 'Alberta', abbreviation: 'ALB', country: 'Canada' } ] } ];

const result = data.reduce((r,c) => Object.keys(c).map(x => r.push({ label: x, items: c[x].map(y => ({label: y.abbreviation, value: y.name }))})) && r, [])

console.log(result)
```

This is the expanded variant:

```js
var data = [ { USA: [ { name: 'Alabama', abbreviation: 'AL', country: 'USA' }, { name: 'Alaska', abbreviation: 'AK', country: 'USA' } ] }, { Canada: [ { name: 'Alberta', abbreviation: 'ALB', country: 'Canada' } ] } ];

const result = data.reduce((r,c) => {
   Object.keys(c).map(x => {
     r.push({ label: x, items: c[x].map(y => ({label: y.abbreviation, value: y.name }))})})
 return r}, [])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Akrion, your solution works fine it compiles and runs. Unfortunately TSlint doesn't like the r.push TSlint thorws error : [ts] Property 'push' does not exist on type 'Object'. Do you have an alternative for this warning?

Comment: Interesting. Try the "longer" version I just added.

Comment: There is Automapper, it would be easy for you to use this if you have .Net experience too... https://www.npmjs.com/package/automapper-ts